# How to remove Bluetooth cache?

Tags: windows-10, audio, bluetooth

I paired a Bose QC35 II headset to my laptop over Bluetooth. The device gives off two bluetooth signals:

"Bose" and
"LE-Bose"

The latter apparently refers to "Low-Energy" mode. The LE device never handles audio so it is useless to connect to if you want to listen to music.

So, I kept on connecting to "Bose" on my laptop and everything worked fine.

One day, I came in and the laptop only lists "LE-Bose". I no longer get "Bose" on the list of available devices. If I remove all bluetooth devices from the headset, and from Windows 10, then Windows automatically connects to the LE bluetooth device... indicating that "Remove device" doesn't actually remove the device state from Windows.

I took this same headset to a co-worker's laptop and he sees both devices. Connecting to the non-LE device yields audio.

So I know the headset is fine and Windows is at fault. I just don't know how to fix it. I tried uninstalling all bluetooth devices from Device Manager but it did not help.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, I ended up reinstalling Windows (which fixed the problem). I couldn't find any other way to fix this.

Comment: I ended up doing the samefor a Logitech keyboard.  I couldn't even remove the device from the Registry, due to some permissions problem.  Even when I set the permissions to "Full Control" for "everyone" it still wouldn't let me remove the device entry.  A clean reinstall fixed it though :-)